# How can I build an AJAX-based website that is both search engine and browser friendly?

Tags: javascript, ajax, seo

I am building a web site that uses AJAX to load its different pages to allow for a faster and more fluid user experience. How can I do this while still allowing my website to be easily indexed by search engines? I also want the browser's back and forward buttons to work as expected. Any ideas on how I could accomplish this?

I know that other web applications like Grooveshark and Gmail already do this, but I'm unsure of how I could implement something like this myself.

Comment: AJAX and crawling don't play together well. Google's proposed some hacks to get around it: http://code.google.com/web/ajaxcrawling/docs/specification.html. Beyond this, the question question should be on the webmaster's site, as it's still at the "projectorware" phase, and does not involve programming.

Comment: Gmail is search engine friendly? How so? Also, @MarcB, people nowadays don't know what a projector is. :)

Comment: @bzlm: dunno, most schools here are using smartboards with digital projectors. May not be a classic projector with transparencies, but the basic concept remains the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start by reading this:

http://code.google.com/web/ajaxcrawling/docs/getting-started.html

Basically, you need to add hash fragments to your URL, each representing the state of the current view. If you were to take the current URL and paste it into another browser, the application would look at the hash and re-execute the ajax activity that creates the same view state.

Comment: Okay so that covers the SEO part. What about the browser back button? Somebody mentioned that I could use window.location.hash somehow, but I'm not quite sure how. (Sorry, I'm a bit new to this.)

Comment: You need to look at AJAX history management. I have used this one: http://code.google.com/p/reallysimplehistory/

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for [SWFAddress](http://www.asual.com/swfaddress/).

> SWFAddress is a small but powerful library that provides deep linking
>   for Flash and Ajax. It's a developer tool, allowing creation of unique
>   virtual URLs that can point to a website section or an application
>   state